# Find recommended monitor resolution in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, resolution, screen-resolution, dxgi

How can I find what Windows marks as the recommended resolution, normally also the native resolution. In many cases the highest supported resolution is also the recommended one, but some monitors list resolutions that are higher and even end up being out-of-range.

[image: Example of recommended resolution being lower than highest supported.]

I've tried several approaches, including [EnumDisplaySettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors) from the Windows API, and using DXGI and the [IDXGIOutput::GetDisplayModeList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgioutput-getdisplaymodelist) method. Both of these list all supported resolutions, but I find no way of detecting which one is recommended. Filtering on for example [DXGI_MODE_DESC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173064(v=vs.85).aspx)::Scaling or other members does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [IDXGIOutput1::FindClosestMatchingMode1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgioutput1-findclosestmatchingmode1) supplying 0 for preferred width and height so they will be automatically selected.

Comment: That is not correct solution.
It'll return current mode, not the one listed as recommended.